# What is error code 35, returned by the telegram.org server

Tags: python, api, telegram

My client often receives the following message container from the telegram server, seemingly at random:

```
{'MessageContainer': [{'msg': {u'bad_msg_notification': {u'bad_msg_seqno': 4, u'bad_msg_id': 6330589643093583872L, u'error_code': 35}}, 'seqno': 4, 'msg_id': 6330589645303624705L}, {'msg': {u'msgs_ack': {u'msg_ids': [6330589643093583872L]}}, 'seqno': 4, 'msg_id': 6330589645303639041L}]})
```

You may notice: **'error code': 35** above, but there is no description of what that error code means. So far I have been ignoring it but that is not a good long term solution IMHO. Any ideas what that error code means?

Comment: have you found an adequate solution for this?

Comment: If sending MsgsAck solves the issue, then yes. I'm implementing that now. I'll let you know if that does the trick.

Comment: The errors associated with `bad_msg_seqno` are just related to incorrect calculation of msg_sequence numbers from your end

Comment: Then I don't understand how I am miscalculating the sequence numbers. They start at zero and increment by one, after switching dc's they go back to zero. Is this incorrect?

Comment: It turns out the code I inherited used one `seqno` for both tcp transmissions and telegram content messages. They are **not** the same!
`TCP messages are sequenced as: 0, 1, 2, 3...`
`Telegram content is sequenced as: 1, 3, 5...`
So as soon as the code matured to sending messages (using the tcp seqno) I ran into these errors. Processing is better now that I've separated the two types of sequence numbers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a set of errors associated with ***bad_msg_seqno***

**From the documentation:**

> Here, error_code can also take on the following values:
>
> 32. msg_seqno too low (the server
>       has already received a message with a lower msg_id but with either a
>       higher or an equal and odd seqno)
> 33. msg_seqno too high (similarly,
>       there is a message with a higher msg_id but with either a lower or
>       an equal and odd seqno)
> 34. an even msg_seqno expected (irrelevant
>       message), but odd received
> 35. odd msg_seqno expected (relevant
>       message), but even received

**Formal Definition:** [Message Sequence Number (msg_seqno)](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/description#message-sequence-number-msg-seqno)

> a 32-bit number equal to twice the number of “content-related”
>   messages (those requiring acknowledgment, and in particular those that
>   are not containers) created by the sender prior to this message and
>   subsequently incremented by one if the current message is a
>   content-related message. A container is always generated after its
>   entire contents; therefore, its sequence number is greater than or
>   equal to the sequence numbers of the messages contained in it.

**Notes:**

1. Every new session starts from seq_no = 1 --> (0 * 2) + 1
2. Every sequence number you send is calculated as: (number_of_content_messages_ already_sent * 2) + 1 hence the all sequence numbers you send are always odd
3. A container messages seq_no == the max seq_no of its content messages
4. The server will always reply you with the correct `server_seq_no` which should be 1 greater than your ***correct*** max seq_no so far.
5. hence a good check / seq_no correction scheme would be to use the latest received `server_seq_no` (which should always be even) to confirm what your `current-expected` seq_no should be, and adjust as required.

The above technique has worked for me in avoiding these intermittent error messages completely.

Comment: How does one programmatically know a message is a "content message"? For example, the methods used to create an auth key are not content messages (so far as I understand them) but the only thing that seems to make them programmatically unique is they are sent unencrypted since the auth key is required to do encryption. Is there anything else that differentiates content versus non-content? For example, are `MsgAcks` considered content messages?

Comment: Best rule of thumb: look at the docs:  anything that forms part of **Main application API** is content  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/master/Telegram/SourceFiles/mtproto/scheme.tl

Comment: I was afraid of that, there is no way for a client to "look at the docs". It seems the only answer is to hard code a list of non-content messages, which could be problematic since the API schema is subject to layer updates.

Comment: but "YOU" are the one building the client... you need to code this in, and it does not change. Notice that when Layer changes, it is usually just addition of new features to existing types or new types and new functions. The core system functions and MTProto types hardly ever change. Also, your client is coded to a specific schema Layer, so again not affected by Layer changes.

Comment: What about sequence numbers for non-content messages? For example, if I start the process to create an auth key by calling `res_pq` with sequence number 0 and increment by one for subsequent calls the auth key is created fine. But if I start by calling `res_pq` with sequence number 1 the server does not respond. Are there separate seqno algorithms for content and non-content messages?

Comment: authKey creation are all plain-text... msg_id and sequence_no only apply for none-plain text messages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124573/discussion-between-charles-okwuagwu-and-kenny-cason).

Answer (score 1):

As [Telegram API docs](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/service_messages_about_messages) says, error with code 35 is "odd msg_seqno expected (relevant message), but even received"

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that page. Can you please explain how to handle these messages? It is unclear to me from the documentation how this situation occurs and it's ramifications.

Comment: Also, the documentation states messages must be acknowledged. Does that mean I need to Ack back to the server? If so, what method is used to accomplish this?

Comment: You can send you acks with your next request or, accumulate your acks then send after a period

Comment: What mechanism is implemented to send the acks? All I see in the schema is: `msgs_ack#62d6b459 msg_ids:Vector<long> = MsgsAck;` but no method to send this data type.

Comment: Per a different question, a `msgs_ack` is sent back to the server as if it is a method instead of a data type. If your client builds it's methods from the TL schema you will have to take special action to build this as a method as well as a data type. Ditto with msg_container if you use those.