# Acknowledging telegram.org server responses

Tags: api, telegram

The telegram [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/service_messages_about_messages) states:

> Receipt of virtually all messages (with the exception of some purely
>   service ones as well as the plain-text messages used in the protocol
>   for creating an authorization key) must be acknowledged. This requires
>   the use of the following service message (not requiring an
>   acknowledgment):

```
msgs_ack#62d6b459 msg_ids:Vector long = MsgsAck;
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515953/what-is-error-code-35-returned-by-the-telegram-org-server) alludes to sending acks back to the server but not the mechanism by which those acks are sent. I attempted sending a `MsgsAck` and a `msgs_ack` to the server but they failed because those are data types, not constructors (methods). This leads me to two questions:

1. How does a telegram client send acks back to the server? (both individually and as part of a method call)
2. How does a telegram client differentiate between server responses that require an ack and those who don't? (it appears responses that include a req_msg_id require an ack, but I'd like confirmation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way to go about this is:

1) accumulate the msg_ids that you receive for from the server - those that need to be acknowledged as indicated in the documentation: these are all *content related* messages, not service messages

2) Every time you want to send new messages to the server, you could include your accumulated acknowledgment messages in a message container along with the messages you intend to send.

3) If you have accumulated msg_ids to be acknowledged for over a period say X minutes, without an opportunity to clear them via step 2) above, then you can simply send an acknowledgment message back to telegram wit the list of msg_ids to be acknowledged.

To send an acknowledgement use this:

```
msgs_ack#62d6b459 msg_ids:Vector<long> = MsgsAck;
```

Comment: That sounds simple but according to the schema `MsgsAck` is a data _type_, not a _method_. Are you saying I should send a MsgsAck back to the server as raw data instead of wrapped by some method? Ditto for MessageContainer: it is a type, not a method. @CharlesOkwuagwu

Comment: That is correct. You presently send message containers, you can similarly send MsgsAck